# I need to load an XML file and use it as a user interface

Tags: html, user-interface, xml-parsing

Here is an example of a file I need to load in the context of a game menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Menus version="1.0">
    <Menu number ="0" type ="1" title ="Start Menu" bgbitmap ="bg01.png">
        <Button position ="0" title ="New\nGame" bitmap ="newgame.png" vsize ="1" hsize ="3">
            <Action type ="onclick" command ="startNewGame">
                <Parameter name ="authority" value ="admin" />
                <Parameter name ="disabled" value ="false" />
            </Action>
        </Button>
        <Button position ="1" title ="Load\nGame" bitmap ="load game.png" vsize ="1" hsize ="3">
            <Action type ="onclick" command ="loadGame">
                <Parameter name ="authority" value ="admin" />
                <Parameter name ="disabled" value ="false" />
            </Action>
        </Button>
    </Menu>
    <Menu number ="1" type ="1" title ="Settings Menu" bgbitmap ="bg01.png">
        <Button position ="0" title ="VSync Off" bitmap ="vsync.png" vsize ="1" hsize ="1">
            <Action type ="onload" command ="loadVsyncValue" />
            <Action type ="onclick" command ="toggleVsync">
                <Parameter name ="authority" value ="admin" />
                <Parameter name ="disabled" value ="false" />
            </Action>
        </Button>
        <Button position ="1" title ="FullScreen Off" bitmap ="fullscreen.png" vsize ="1" hsize ="1">
            <Action type ="onload" command ="loadFSValue" />
            <Action type ="onclick" command ="toggleFS">
                <Parameter name ="authority" value ="admin" />
                <Parameter name ="disabled" value ="false" />
            </Action>
        </Button>
    </Menu>
</Menus>
```

Is it possible to load up a sort of tiled menu and display it, using Javascript, with the Canvas element?
I have a small amount of experience with HTML/CSS/JS but don't really understand XML parsing or anything like that

I have looked through tickets before but none quite detail what I need for this project.

Any sort of help would be appreciated!!

Edit - I should have mentioned I want to use the Canvas element to display the images mentioned in the XML file.

Comment: XML can be transformed using XSLT to HTML, for instance. But note that your posted sample is not really XML at all, it has the wrong quote characters (should be ASCII quotes e.g. `"`) as the delimiters for most attribute values.